How to Fix "502 Bad Gateway" Error When Deploying Next.js to Google App Engine in Development Mode
I’m encountering a "502 Bad Gateway" error when deploying my Next.js project to Google App Engine using a development configuration. I want to run the app in development mode using npm run dev, but the deployment fails with this error.
Current Setup:

Next.js Project: Using standard Next.js scripts for development, build, and start.
app.yaml Configuration: The configuration file is set up to use development mode.

app.yaml File:
runtime: nodejs18

service: nextjs-app

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'development'

entrypoint: npm run dev

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto

package.json Scripts:
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
}

Issue:
When deploying with the above configuration, I receive a "502 Bad Gateway" error from Nginx. This suggests that the server is not able to connect to or properly serve the Next.js application.
Questions:

Configuration: Is there something incorrect in the app.yaml that could be causing the 502 error?
Development Mode: Is using npm run dev appropriate for deployment on Google App Engine, or should I be using a different approach?
Troubleshooting: What steps can I take to troubleshoot and resolve the 502 Bad Gateway error in this setup?

What I Tried:

Configuration Changes:

I set the app.yaml file to use the Node.js runtime with npm run dev as the entry point for development mode.

The app.yaml file includes the following configuration:
runtime: nodejs18

service: nextjs-app

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'development'

entrypoint: npm run dev

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto




Scripts in package.json:

The relevant scripts in package.json are configured as follows:
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
}




Deployment:

Deployed the application using Google Cloud's deployment tools (gcloud app deploy).



What I Was Expecting:

I expected the Next.js application to run in development mode as specified by npm run dev.
The application should start up without errors, and I should be able to access it via the provided URL without encountering a "502 Bad Gateway" error.

Issue Encountered:

Upon deployment, I receive a "502 Bad Gateway" error, indicating that the gateway server (Nginx) is unable to communicate with the application server.


Please include the initial (log) output when running the command locally. I suspect (!?) that it's either binding to localhost (127.0.0.1) which means it will be inaccessible outside of the host. And/or it's not using port 8080.

Another debugging solution is to identify the container that App Engine flex has built for your process and try running it locally.
